# How do you check that the user entered a String value instead of a number?

Tags: java, string, input, while-loop

I wrote a simple program that calculates the hypotenuse of a triangle when the user inputs side A and B. I have a while loop that prompts the user to enter a value greater than 0 if they do, but how do I check if the user enters a String value?

`while (sideA<=0 || sideB<=0)`{

What should I add so if the user enters a string value, the loop will also start?

Thanks

Comment: Try and convert the `String` to numeric value, catch the `NumberFormatException`

Comment: How are you receiving the user input? I mean, depending on how you do it, all user input comes in as a String, even "9375", so you're gonna need to be more specific. If you wanna see if the String only contains numbers, you could use `string.matches("[0-9]+");`, which checks if the String contains only numbers 0-9. the `+` quantifier means *one or more*

Answer (score 2):

However you get your input (from command line, scanner or buffered reader) first parse it and try to store it in an integer variable.  If its a string, then catch the exception and allow the user to enter the value again.

```
try 
{
   int sideA = Integer.parseInt(input);
} 
catch (NumberFormatException ex) 
{
  //Do something here to keep continuing the while loop

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  // requesting user input
  System.out.println("Enter x and y : ");

  String x = input.next();
  String y = input.next();

  try {
     double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
     double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2);

     if(d1 > 0 && d2 > 0) {
        //Call for the hypotenuse method
        double z = hypotenuse(d1,d2);
     }
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use the binary instanceof operator. it returns a boolean value in this manner:

```
if( myVariable instanceof String )
    //it's a string!
else
    //it's not a string
```

This approach can of course be used to check for other types as well. I recommend type checking your A and B variables as strings using **instanceof** and handle accordingly

Comment: Im guessing its because user input doesnt usually come in as object form, so we are forced to assume the asker is receiving the input as a String, and is asking how to check if it contains numbers. The asker was not specific when asking, so I understand the confusion. One of the downvoters should have said this. The fact no one asked the person to fix up his question is pretty depressing, but answering before you fully understood the cryptic question was where you made a wrong move. Thats a big reason why most of my "answers" are actually in the comment section. This site needs to be cleaned..

Comment: And by object form, I mean plain object form (using Object as the type rather than the actual type), not object like how String is an object

Comment: I follow, all input is a string, so my solution would always resolve the input as a string. The problem is checking if what is contained within the string is an integer. Roger that, thanks for the response!

Comment: Thats not true; not all input comes in as a String, for example, when using RMI or an ObjectInputStream, so even I could have gotten confused